# Is it possible to load a GWT project in a Frame?

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I have developed some kind of "mainframe" for my GWT app. This mainframe holds a GWT Frame object in which I want to load another GWT project, just like you can easily load HTML pages in iframes. The two projects are in the same workspace and I'm using the Eclipse Plugin. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your frame and use this:

```
RootPanel.get("yourFrameId").add(YourWidget);
```

This should work.